# not able to display binary tree

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

the code is getting compiled but not displaying result.
  i have used the method insertIntoBinaryTree() to insert a node into the binary tree and the method printLevelOrder() to display the binary tree level wise. but it is not displaying anything.please check the code .

```
public class BinaryTree {


public class TreeNode{

    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;
    int data;

    TreeNode(int data)
    {
        this.left=null;
        this.right=null;
        this.data=data;
    }

    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }


    public void setData(int data)
    {

        this.data=data;

    }


    public void setLeft(TreeNode left)
    {
        this.left=left;

    }

    public void setRight(TreeNode right)
    {
        this.right=right;
    }


    public TreeNode getLeft()
    {
        return left;
    }
    public TreeNode getRight()
    {
        return right;
    }


}

TreeNode root;

BinaryTree()
{
    root=null;

}


public void insertRoot(int data)
{
    TreeNode node= new TreeNode(data);
    root=node;
}

public void insertIntoBinaryTree(int data)
{
    TreeNode node= new TreeNode(data);

    Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();

    TreeNode temp;
    q.offer(root);

    while(!q.isEmpty())
    {
        temp=q.poll();


        if(temp!=null)
        {

            if(temp.getLeft()!=null)
            {
                q.offer(temp.getLeft());
            }

            else
            {
                temp.setLeft(node);

            }

            if(temp.getRight()!=null)
            {
                q.offer(temp.getRight());
            }

            else
            {
                temp.setRight(node);

            }

        }
    }

}



public void printLevelOrder()
{

    TreeNode cur;

    Queue<TreeNode> ql= new LinkedList<TreeNode>();

    ql.offer(root);

    while(!ql.isEmpty())
    {

        cur= ql.poll();

        System.out.println(cur.getData()+ " ");

        if(cur.getLeft()!=null)
            ql.offer(cur.getLeft());

        if(cur.getRight()!=null)
        {
            ql.offer(cur.getRight());
        }


    }

}       
 public static void main(String args[])
    {

        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();
        bt.insertRoot(1);
        bt.insertIntoBinaryTree(2);
        bt.insertIntoBinaryTree(3);
        bt.insertIntoBinaryTree(4);
        bt.insertIntoBinaryTree(5);
        bt.insertIntoBinaryTree(6);
        bt.printLevelOrder();




}


}
```

Comment: what do you call to print the tree? Do you have a main method or a test case?

Comment: yes i have added the main method. please check for the error

Comment: Time to (learn to) use a debugger

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create an ordered binary tree? I assume you are, but if that's the case, then something that is obviously missing from `insertIntoBinaryTree` is any kind of comparison between the value being added (`data`) and the value at the current node of the tree (`temp.getData()`). You want to go left if the new value is less than the value at the current node and right if the value is greater. (You can choose either if they are the same.)

The first time your code calls `insertIntoBinaryTree`, it's going to add the new node as *both* the left and right members of the root, because the logic just checks both for null. Now you have a malformed tree, because the left and right members both reference the same node, and things go downhill from there.

I would start with just the root and one additional node, and see if you can get it working that way, then carry on from there.

I've never seen the use of a queue to print a binary tree before, but I suppose it work. Usually people use recursion. But you definitely don't need a queue to insert data into a binary tree. Since you only go left or right (never both), the queue will only ever have one item and can be replaced with a variable.